# Formula to give the value of corresponding header cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using the following formula to search the range `'Pick Entry'!B2:X50` for cells that either match or contain within *"/"* delimiters the value of cell `A4`, and then report the value of the corresponding cell in the header column (range `'Pick Entry'!A2:A50`).

For example, if a match is found in `'Pick Entry'!D7`, then the formula will report the value of `'Pick Entry'!A7`.

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        'Pick Entry'!$A$2:$A$50,
        SMALL(
            IF(
                MMULT(
                    --(
                        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/" & TEXT($A4, "0") & "/", 'Pick Entry'!$B$2:$X$50)) +
                            EXACT(TEXT($A4, "0"), 'Pick Entry'!$B$2:$X$50)
                    ),
                    TRANSPOSE(COLUMN('Pick Entry'!$B$2:$X$50) ^ 0)
                ) > 0,
                ROW('Pick Entry'!$A$2:$A$50) - ROW('Pick Entry'!$A$2) + 1,
                ""
            ),
            COLUMNS($B1:B1)
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

This formula is working well for that purpose. **However,** I'm having a heck of a time coming up with a similar formula that reports the value of the corresponding cell in the header row (`'Pick Entry'!B1:X1`).

Any suggestions?

tried various permutations of the formula to no avail

Comment: A little data and expected result with that data would help. You can add that using markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Also, are you on Office 365 or Excel 2021?

Comment: Actually figured out a VBA solution. Thanks everyone.